# Changing Navigation bar text color

Tags: ios, uinavigationitem, xamarin.ios

So I have a navbar but I want to change the text color to black. I think I have to add a new label to the navbar and customize that label. I tried this:

```
navbar.TopItem.TitleView.Add BarLabel = new UILabel();
BarLabel.TextColor = UIColor.Black;
```

But that didn't work. Or something like this:

```
[self.myBarButton setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[UIColor blackColor] forKey:UITextAttributeTextColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

But what would this be in C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

googling gave me this: http://www.developersalley.com/blog/post/2012/03/04/How-To-Change-The-Font-Of-MonoTouchUIKitUINavigationBar.aspx

Changing the color is very similar